# When donwloading a pdf file on React, its showed as blank instead of showing the data

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to generate a pdf report and download it from my frontend app, so that users can get reports.

I've created the function on my backend app, if i make a request to the backend endpoint with postman, i can see the pdf preview correctly, with all the data, titles and more.

But when i fetch the endpoint from my front end app, the download is made with a blank pdf instead of the data.

This is my backend function:

```
const getPacientesWithEscolaridad = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const report = await db.query('Call GetPacientesWithEscolaridad();');

  const data = {
    title: 'Pacientes con Escolaridad',
    heading: 'Pacientes con Escolaridad',
    pacientes: report.map((paciente) => {
      return {
        nombre: paciente.Nombre,
        contacto: paciente.Contacto,
        edad: paciente.Edad,
        nacionalidad: paciente.Nacionalidad,
        genero: paciente.Genero,
        tipoEducacion: paciente.TipoEducacion,
        anoEscolar: paciente.AnoEscolar,
        centroEducativo: paciente.CentroEducativo,
        ultimoAnoAprobado: paciente.UltimoAnoAprobado,
        adecuacion: paciente.Adecuacion,
        fechaDeSalida: paciente.FechaDeSalida,
        motivoSalida: paciente.MotivoSalida,
      };
    }),
  };

  try {
    const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, '../pdf/template.hbs');
    const templateContent = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf-8');
    const compiledTemplate = handlebars.compile(templateContent);
    const html = compiledTemplate(data);

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setContent(html);
    await page.emulateMediaType('print');

    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
      format: 'A4',
      printBackground: true,
    });

    await browser.close();

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="output.pdf"');
    res.send(pdfBuffer);

    console.log('PDF generated and sent successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error generating or sending PDF:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error generating or sending PDF.' });
  }
});
```

This is my react component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const ReportDownload = () => {
  const [downloadLink, setDownloadLink] = useState('');

  const fetchPDFReport = async () => {
    try {
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get('jwt')}`,
        
      };
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_API}stats/GetPacientesWithEscolaridad`,
        {
          headers,
          responseType: 'arrayBuffer ', // Important to specify the response type as 'blob'
        }
      );

      // Create a Blob URL to display and download the PDF
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
      setDownloadLink(pdfUrl);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching PDF report:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchPDFReport}>Fetch PDF Report</button>
      {downloadLink && (
        <div>
          <a href={downloadLink} download="output .pdf">
            Download PDF Report
          </a>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportDownload;
```